# How could I make a drawing app open when I tap my pen in a corner of the drawing tablet (Wacom One S)?

Tags: scripts, python, 22.04, wacom

I want to be able to open an app, GIMP or Obsidian, when I tap my pen in the top left corner of my drawing tablet (Wacom One S), I would also like to be able to click in the same spot again  to minimize said app.

I looked for an app which could do what I wanted, but couldn't find any. I wanted to ask if anybody has a good solution for what I would want. I am thinking that a good idea would be to make a python script, but I don't have a lot of experience with python, if anybody has suggestions I would appricate some help.

Comment: Hey man. Can you please tell me what Ubuntu version using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and would like to configure it with a Wacom One S